# WordPress: Maximum Input Variation Limitation

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

Trying to fully implement a new theme (Jannah) in my bitnami wordpress but I got an error message as below:

1000 - Recommended Value: 3000. Max input vars limitation will truncate POST data such as menus.

I increased the max input vars in my php.ini file, restarted my aparche, still no effect. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

You need to edit your `installdir\php\php.ini` file. Find the line:

```
; max_input_vars = 1000
```

and change it to

```
max_input_vars = 3000
```

After that, open your `installdir\manager-windows.exe` and restart Apache on the `Manage Servers` tab.

You could check the change by executing:

```
installdir\wordpress-4.8-0\php\php.exe -i | FindStr max_input_vars
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I did just that, still nothing happen. phpinfo output still showing 1000 instead of 3000, so frustrating!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the semicolon ";" before the sentence.